# How to render variable from placeholders in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid

I'm creating some message suggestions that a user can click on to populate a text area. When displayed the generic strings must render with the user's details.

This is what I am trying to do, but this example uses html coded messages that are not fetched from the database:

```
<ul>
    <li><a><%= "#{@user.name} is the best" %></a></li>
    <li><a><%= "#{@user.name} is the worst" %></a></li>
    <li><a><%= "I think #{@user.name} is the best" %></a></li>
    <li><a><%= "I think #{@user.name} is the worst" %></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to store generic strings with 'placeholders' in a database and only calculate the values in the view.

This is how I've attempted to create the strings in the database (in the seed file)

```
Suggestion.create(message: '#{@user.name} is the best')
Suggestion.create(message: '<%= #{@user.name} %> is the best')
Suggestion.create(message: '<%= @user.name %> is the best')
```

In the view I have an iteration of

```
<%= suggestion.message %>
```

I'm attempting to add the ruby code to the view before it renders. Probably a dumb idea.

This is what is displayed in the html source

```
&lt;%= @user.name %&gt; is the best
&lt;%= #{@user.name} %&gt; is the best
#{@user.name} is the best
```

Here is something similar but it appends the message which won't work as the variable is in different places inside each message:

```
<ul>
    <% @suggestions.each do |message| %>
        <li><a><%= "#{@user.name} message" %></a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your view is probably using the `.html` extension instead of `.html.erb`

Comment: It is using the .erb extension

Comment: Where is the `<a>` tag? In a string in the code, or in the view?

Comment: When you hit that page with your browser, what does your log file show?

Comment: The <a> tag is in the view. What I want to do is write a bunch of generic messages and display them on the page with the logged in users values. My first idea was to use the actual rails code <%= @user.name %> as the place holder so when the string was returned to the view it already had the ruby code to display the user's values. It doesn't work however as it just displays the actual rails code and not the calculated values.

Comment: You need to show us more code. Can you submit your project to github so we can review it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've tried to add a clearer explanation if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to store a set of templates in a database and then render those templates to your view.

You should use Liquid

http://liquidmarkup.org/

Example snippet:

```
<ul id="products">
  {% for product in products %}
    <li>
      <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
      Only {{ product.price | format_as_money }}

      <p>{{ product.description | prettyprint | truncate: 200  }}</p>

    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Code to render

```
Liquid::Template.parse(template).render 'products' => Product.find(:all)
```

How you could use this:

```
class Suggestion < AR::Base
  validate :message, presence: true

  def render_with(user)
    Liquid::Template.parse(message).render user: user
  end
end


Suggestion.create(message: "{{user.name}} is the best")
Suggestion.create(message: "{{user.name}} is the worst")
Suggestion.create(message: "{{user.name}} is the awesome")

<ul>
  <% Suggestion.all.each do |suggestion| %>
    <li><%= suggestion.render_with(@user) %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! Really appreciate the example of how I could use liquid in my example. I had to add: def to_liquid {'name'=>self.name} end to the user model though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but here are some possible solutions that work when `@user` might be `nil`:

```
"#{@user.try(:name)} is the best in the biz"
"%s is the best in the biz" % @user.try(:name)
"#{name} is the best in the biz" % { name: @user.try(:name) }
```

[`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)  will return nil if called on nil.

If the html output is still escaped, try one of:

```
raw(expression)
expression.html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show this message for each user, then you should make it a method call:

```
class Suggestion < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def default_message
    "#{user.name} is the best"
  end
end

@user       = User.new(name: "Bob")
@suggestion = Suggestion.create(user: @user)
@suggestion.default_message #=> "Bob is the best"
```

Comment: It doesnt work in the seed file because it tries to interpolate the string (and gives the error that @user is nil) when I want it to store the rails code

Comment: I don't want it to store the calculated values for every user. The idea is to store the generic versions of the message so that it can be worked out when displayed.

Comment: I don't want it to store the calculated values for every user.

Comment: It doesn't. It stores the user id.

Comment: The messages aren't stored. They're generated when you call the `default_message`.

Comment: The example in your original question does this. My code doesn't.